# Find differences between two json objects

Tags: c#, json, diff

Are there any libraries in .Net to help compare and find differences between two json objects? I've found some solutions available for JavaScript, but nothing interesting for C#. The point of my question is to create json with changes marked in some way, based on the comparison. So that the user could see where the changes are.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect differences between two json files in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034224/detect-differences-between-two-json-files-in-c-sharp)

Comment: There's a nice library available here that does exactly that: https://github.com/wbish/jsondiffpatch.net

Answer (score 14):

```
using Microsoft.XmlDiffPatch;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Convert each json to xml and use MS XmlDiff libary. Available on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XMLDiffPatch/). Differences are given in another xml doc which here I write to the console. This is suitable for unit testing for example.

```
public bool CompareJson(string expected, string actual)
{
    var expectedDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(expected, "root");
    var actualDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(actual, "root");
    var diff = new XmlDiff(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreWhitespace |
                           XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var result = diff.Compare(expectedDoc, actualDoc, writer);
        if (!result)
        {
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the IgnoreChildOrder flag imply that the order of elements in JSON arrays is ignored?

Comment: Maybe, worth trying. I'm not working on a windows machine at the moment, so I can't try right now. If you try, let me know.

Comment: @JørgenFogh Just call it with `CompareJson("{\"a\":[1,2]}", "{\"a\":[2,1]}");`

Comment: **Yes** it will ignore the order of elements

Answer (score 8):

I have used different JSON objects than those in your example but it will apply to your case correctly.

```
private static string GetJsonDiff(string action, string existing, string modified, string objectType)
    {
        // convert JSON to object
        JObject xptJson = JObject.Parse(modified);
        JObject actualJson = JObject.Parse(existing);

        // read properties
        var xptProps = xptJson.Properties().ToList();
        var actProps = actualJson.Properties().ToList();

        // find differing properties
        var auditLog = (from existingProp in actProps
            from modifiedProp in xptProps
            where modifiedProp.Path.Equals(existingProp.Path)
            where !modifiedProp.Value.ToString().Equals(existingProp.Value.ToString())
            select new AuditLog
            {
                Field = existingProp.Path,
                OldValue = existingProp.Value.ToString(),
                NewValue = modifiedProp.Value.ToString(),
                Action = action, ActionBy = GetUserName(),
                ActionDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongDateString(),
                ObjectType = objectType
            }).ToList();

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(auditLog);
    }
```

Comment: How to use this function with a array of objects. I have 100 of objects in existing JArray and same on modified JArray ?

Comment: recursion is missing

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet is to use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to create two JSON objects, then recursively loop through the tree, comparing each node to see if it exists and is equal while you go.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to go here is to create objects using newtonsoft json.http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

So, you will have two objects of the same type, which you can easily compare and mark the differences.

Answer (score -1):

```
private IEnumerable<JProperty> JSONCompare(string expectedJSON, string actualJSON)
{
    // convert JSON to object
    JObject xptJson = JObject.Parse(expectedJSON);
    JObject actualJson = JObject.Parse(actualJSON);

    // read properties
    var xptProps = xptJson.Properties().ToList();
    var actProps = actualJson.Properties().ToList();

    // find missing properties
    var missingProps = xptProps.Where(expected => actProps.Where(actual => actual.Name == expected.Name).Count() == 0);

    return missingProps;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this missing recursive support?

Comment: Does it take the actual structure into consideration, or is it content with finding a keys of the same name anywhere in the structure?